# Ionic Footer Hiding half

Tags: ionic2, ionic3

```
<ion-footer>
<ion-toolbar>
    <ion-row>
        <ion-col col-6>
            <button ion-button full color="secondary">ADD TO CART</button>

        </ion-col>

        <ion-col col-6>
            <button ion-button full color="primary">BUY NOW</button>
        </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
</ion-toolbar>
```

ionic Footer Hiding Sometimes on Android Devices Also Toaster Notification Also hiding half In this Situation

[image]

Comment: Did you solve your issue? I am facing similiar problem and running out of options. Would be great if you can add solution or accept answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Need to increase height of `navbar` using override shared variable in variable.scss**

```
$navbar-md-height: your height;
```